# Cron expression for every 20 minutes in between 12:00 AM to 12:59 AM, only on Saturday

Tags: cron, azure-webjobs

I like to schedule an Azure WebJob for the following scenario:

> Every 20 minutes in between 12:00 AM to 12:59 AM, only on Saturday.

i.e., I expect the web job to be run on 3 occurrences: `12:00 AM`, `12:20 AM`, and `12:40 AM` on Saturday.

So, will the Cron Expression: `0 */20 0,1 * * 6` satisfy the scenario?
If not, please someone suggest the correct expression for the same.

Comment: I got the [CronExpression tool](https://cronexpressiondescriptor.azurewebsites.net/?expression=0+*%2F20+0+*+*+Sat&locale=en) to validate the scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right cron should be `0 */20 0 * * Sat`, if you set it with `0 */20 0,1 * * 6`, it will also run at `1:00`, `1:20` and `1:40`.
More details refer to this doc: [NCRONTAB expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions).

[image]