# How can i schedule a job between 04:00 and 21:00 on every 5 minutes with Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

I need to schedule a job on Azure.
I need to schedule the job between 04:00 and 21:00 every 5 minutes.

I try the below cron expression but it didn't work.

0 */5 4-21 * * *

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to schedule a job on Azure. I need to schedule the job between
> 04:00 and 21:00 every 5 minutes.

To do that one of the workaround could be able to solve the above issue,

If you want to use the ***cron expression*** to run every 5 minutes between 04:00- 21:00 , you can use in your json as below:

`{"schedule": "0,05 4-21 * * *"}`

For more information please refer this ***[Blog](https://coderedirect.com/questions/442074/azure-webjob-scheduler-every-30-minutes-from-8am-6pm)*** post & ***[SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59821008/cron-expression-for-every-20-minutes-in-between-1200-am-to-1259-am-only-on-sa?rq=1)***.